# Use of unresolved identifier 'InstanceID' Firebase 6.2.2

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am always getting a weird error:-

> Use of unresolved identifier 'InstanceID'

I also tried to check by replacing it with FIRInstanceID. but problem error remains the same.

import Firebase

```
    InstanceID.instanceID().deleteID { error in
        if error != nil{
            completion(ConstantLocalizeString.Something_went_wrong)
        }
     }
```

pod installed

> Firebase (6.22.0)
>
> FirebaseAnalytics (6.4.1)
>
> FirebaseAuth (6.5.1)
>
> FirebaseAuthInterop (1.1.0)
>
> FirebaseCore (6.6.6)
>
> FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(1.2.3)
>
> FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.2.0)
>
> FirebaseDatabase (6.1.4)
>
> FirebaseInstallations(1.1.1)
>
> GTMSessionFetcher (1.3.1)
>
> Gloss (2.1.1)
>
> GoogleAnalytics (3.17.0)
>
> GoogleAppMeasurement (6.4.1)
>
> GoogleDataTransport (5.1.1)
>
> GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (2.0.2)
>
> GoogleUtilities(6.5.2)

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found the solution.I missed the 
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

Pod I am using are:-  pod 'CodableFirebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'

Also in the class, I have to replace the import Firebase to import FirebaseInstanceID

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a step back and revisit the code itself and make sure it is doing something you want.

`FirebaseInstanceID` is in the process of being deprecated and is being replaced by `FirebaseInstallations`. In past releases, `FirebaseInstanceID` was installed as a dependency of `FirebaseAnalytics`, but that is no longer the case.

Comment: If I replace FirebaseInstanceID with FirebaseInstallations. it again started showing the error Use of unresolved identifier 'InstanceID'

But if I import FirebaseInstanceID, I am able to access   InstanceID.instanceID().deleteID

Comment: Understood, but why do you want to delete the InstanceID ID if the app isn't using instanceID?

Comment: I am using InstanceID for various purpose

Comment: If you're directly using it, `pod 'FirebaseInstanceID'`should be in the Podfile.  Otherwise it will break again when FirebaseMessaging stops depending upon it.